# Python pandas: groupby is creating additional rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which contains the following columns: 'country', 'year', 'suicides_no'.
I would like to perform groupby by 'country' and 'year' and sum on 'suicides_no' column. So I use the following:

```
df_temp = df_suicides.groupby(['country', 'year'], as_index = False)['suicides_no'].agg('sum')
```

However the problem is that if some years are missing it returns rows with country name and year and  value 0 and I would like to have this rows excluced from the returned dataframe. Any suggenstion how I should correct it?

Thanks

Comment: You want to filter out (remove) rows where the value of a particular column is zero?

Answer (score 0):

You can mask to keep the rows which do not contain zero:

```
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp['suicides_no'].ne(0)]
```